# Is this proof for Theorem 16.4 Munkres Topology correct?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, order-topology

The followings is the Theorem $16.4$ from Munkres' Topology:

[image]

In the textbook it uses concept of subbasis to prove the theorem which I can't understand it. I tried to prove that in another way but I am not sure if I am correct.

Proof?:

1- Both $Y$ and $\emptyset$ are open in both typologies.

2- Basis elements in order topology in $Y$ are one of the three types: (1) All open intervals $(a,b)$ in $Y$; (2) All intervals of the form $[a_0,b)$, where $a_0$ is the smallest element (if any) of $Y$; (2) All intervals of the form $(a,b_0]$, where $b_0$ is the largest element (if any) of $Y$. Each of them can be written as $(c,d) \cap Y$ for $(c,d) \subset X$ an open set in $X$. And since $(c,d) \cap Y$ is open so the topology $Y$ inherited as a subspace of $X$ is finer than order topology in $Y$.

3- Any open set the topology $Y$ inherited as a subspace of $X$ is in the form $(c,d) \cap Y$ for $(c,d) \subset X$ an open set in $X$. This intersection is either $Y$ or $\emptyset$ or one the mentioned types of basis elements in order topology in $Y$ in paragraph 2. So the topology $Y$ inherited as a subspace of $X$ is coarser than order topology in $Y$. And we are done!

Is this proof a correct and rigorous one? And if not, is there any other simple proof not using subbasis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stand to give a bit more detail. Let $\tau_Y$ be the subspace topology on $Y$ and $\tau$ the order topology on $Y$, and for $a,b\in Y$ write $(a,b)_Y$, $(a,b]_Y$, etc. for intervals in the relative order on $Y$. In showing that $\tau\subseteq\tau_Y$, you can specify precisely how the intervals in $Y$ are obtained from intervals in $X$.

- If $a,b\in Y$ with $a<b$, then $(a,b)_Y=(a,b)\cap Y\in\tau_Y$.
- If $a_0=\min Y$, and $b\in Y\setminus\{a_0\}$, then either $a_0=\min X$, in which case $[a_0,b)_Y=[a_0,b)\cap Y\in\tau_Y$, or there is an $a\in(\leftarrow,a_0)$, in which case $[a_0,b)_Y=(a,b)\cap Y\in\tau_Y$.
- The case in which $b_0=\max Y$, $a\in Y\setminus\{b_0\}$, and we consider $(a,b_0]_Y$ is similar.

For the proof that $\tau_Y\subseteq\tau$, note that it is *not* true that every open set in $Y$ is of the form $(c,d)\cap Y$ for some $c,d\in X$ with $x<d$. It isn’t even quite true that these sets form a base for $\tau_Y$: that’s the case if and only if $X$ has neither a minimum nor a maximum element. It’s fine to work with a base for $\tau_Y$, of course, but you do have to split it into three cases, just as in the other part of the proof. Moreover, since $c$ and $d$ need not be in $Y$, even showing that $(c,d)\cap Y\in\tau$ takes a bit of work that you’ve not supplied.

Let $c,d\in X$ with $c<d$, and let $B=(c,d)\cap Y\in\tau_Y$. If $c,d\in Y$, then the convexity of $Y$ ensures that $B=(c,d)_Y\in\tau$, but there’s no reason to assume that $c$ and $d$ are in $Y$. To show that $B\in\tau$, we’ll show that for each $y\in B$ there is a $U_y\in\tau$ such that $y\in U_y\subseteq B$; $B$ will then be a union of members of $\tau$ and hence itself in $\tau$. Let $y\in B$; clearly $c<y<d$.

- If $y$ is neither the minimum nor the maximum element of $B$, there are $u,v\in B$ such that $c<u<y<v<d$. $Y$ is convex, and $u,v\in Y$, so $(u,v)\subseteq Y$, and therefore $(u,v)_Y=(u,v)$. Thus, $y\in(u,v)_Y\subseteq B$, where certainly $(u,v)_Y\in\tau$.
- If $y=\min B$, and there is some $v\in B$ such that $y<v$, there are two possibilities. One is that $y=\min Y$; in that case $[y,v)\subseteq Y$, so $y\in[y,v)_Y\subseteq B$, and $[y,v)_Y\in\tau$. The other is that $y\ne\min Y$, in which case there is some $u\in Y$ such that $u<y$. Clearly $u\le c$, since $y=\min B$, and the convexity of $Y$ then implies that $c\in Y$. But then $y\in(c,v)_Y\subseteq B$, and $(c,v)_Y\in\tau$. (It’s not hard to show that if $y\ne\min Y$, then in fact not only is $c\in Y$, but $c$ is the immediate predecessor of $y$ in $X$: the open interval $(c,y)=(c,y)_Y=\varnothing$.)
- If $y=\max B$, and there is some $u\in B$ such that $u<y$, you can show similarly that either $y=\max Y$, and $y\in(u,y]_Y\subseteq B$ with $(u,v]_Y\in\tau$, or $d\in Y$, and $y\in(u,d)_Y\subseteq B$ with $(u,d)_Y\in\tau$.
- The only remaining possibility is that $y=\min B=\max B$, so that $B=\{y\}$. In this case you can use the same ideas to show that $c,d\in Y$, so that $B=(c,d)_Y\in\tau$.

It really is easier to work with the subbase of open rays: there are fewer cases that need to be handled separately.

Comment: I don't understand, the last case. I believe the only possibility when B={y} is that Y={y}. Am I right?

Comment: @Liebe: No. Suppose that $X=\Bbb Z$, $Y=\{0,1,2\}$, $c=0$, and $d=2$. Then $B=(0,2)\cap Y=\{1\}\ne Y$. You get this case precisely in situations like this one.

Comment: Yes, but still there is no interval U of types in $\tau$ such that $y\in U \subset B$. ?

Comment: @Liebe: Sure there is: $(0,2)$.

Comment: @Liebe: Take whatever time you need.

Comment: As like the other cases, we have to prove that for each $y\in B$ (i.e. for y) there is a $U_y\in\tau$ such that $y\in U_y\subseteq B$. And because B is open in Y (intersection of an open set in X with Y) so we have found $U_y$ to be open and actually $U_y=B$. Am I right?

Comment: Oh, no. That's subsapce topology! I can't find an open set it in order topology in general :( I can't prove there always exists one of the open interval types of order topology that is subset of Y contains y.

Comment: @Liebe: You were indeed right: in that last case $c$ and $d$ are necessarily both in $Y$, so $(c,d)=(c,d)_Y=\{y\}=B$. $B$ is in fact in both $\tau$ and $\tau_Y$.

Comment: The problem is that one point is not open in $\tau$. And I can't prove there always exists one of the open interval types of order topology that is subset of Y contains y and is open in $\tau$

Comment: @Liebe: In that particular case it most certainly is. The points $c,y$, and $d$ are exactly like $0,1$, and $2$ in the example: they are adjacent in that order, so that $\{y\}$ *is* the open interval $(c,d)$.